# SqlException on storing data into SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I get the following exception when inserting data into SQL Server database.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at SubjectDataAccess.InsertUrls(String url, String urltitle, String urldetails, String favicon, String imagedata) in d:\project\New Folder\March 5\March 5\ProfileTenModified\App_Code\SubjectsDataAccessLayer\SubjectDataAccess.cs:line 723}

The data is

Url:

```
http://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/space/photos/10-places-on-earth-that-resemble-alien-planets/etosha-pan-namibia
```

Title:

```
10 places on Earth that resemble alien planets: Etosha pan, Namibia
```

does the 10 is in the beginning cause an issue...

Comment: what is the size of the table column, is it smaller than the data?

Comment: I have set them to nvarchar (max)..

Comment: what about the parameter if you are using one

Comment: command parameter, please edit the question and put your code

Comment: yes you are right problem with the Datatype. it is not max as I expected .. Thanks

Comment: put this into answer @MEYWD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the data is smaller than the data size on your table